# google sheet: combine countifs() and trim()

Tags: google-sheets

I use

`=trim(cell)<>""`

to check if the cell is not blank/null or white space.

I want to count how many row from row1 to row100 where there is no blank or null or any white space(s) in the column A or B. So it will count only if both column A and B has value (not blank/null/space).

When using countifs() to count item using multiple criteria. I can't use trim() as the parameter. For example :

```
countifs( trim(A2:A100) , "<>**" , trim(B2:B100) , "<>**")
```

It will give me error.

if i use :

```
countifs( A2:A100 , "<>**" , B2:B100 , "<>**")
```

That can't catch single or multiple space like " " or "     " etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use countifs for this problem.

As you can see in this [article](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function) if you need complex condition you need to use "SUMPRODUCT" on this [article](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) referenced from the previews one.

For you problem this is the solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TRIM(A1:A100)<>""), --(TRIM(B1:B100)<>""))
```

Explanation inside the article.

If you need more help with understand it let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the range an array forumla

```
countifs( {trim(A2:A100)} , "<>**" , {trim(B2:B100)} , "<>**")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

`=COUNTA(FILTER(ROW(A2:A),A2:A&B2:B<>""))`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(TRIM(A2:A100); "<>**"; TRIM(B2:B100); "<>**"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
=countif(ArrayFormula(TRIM(G:G)),trim(G1))
```

Comment: The above formula does not depend on A2:A100 and B2:B100 input ranges, mentioned in question. How can it be a solution?